# How do I call a class integer and add increase it's value?

Tags: python, django

We have a class in our models.py:

```
class Score(model.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

We want to call the score object and update it inside of our views.py, when an answer is correct:

```
def answer(request, level_id):
    # next three lines are working for us.
    o = Level.objects.get(id=level_id)
    guess = request.GET.get('guess', '').strip()
    correct = o.answers.filter(value__iexact=guess).exists()

    b = Score.objects.get('score')
    b.score += o.points
    b.save()
```

We still haven't made b.score += o.points run using an `if` statement, because first I wanted to see if we can update b.score.

```
class Level(model.Models):
    points = models.IntegerField("Point Value')
```

The error we get is:

```
ValueError at /answer/1 too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Can you post a complete [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
def answer(request, level_id):
    # next three lines are working for us.
    o = Level.objects.get(id=level_id)
    guess = request.GET.get('guess', '').strip()
    correct = o.answers.filter(value__iexact=guess).exists()

    b = Score.objects.get(score)
    b.score += int(o.points)
    b.save()
```

You are missing on saving the object, when you update it.

```
    b.save() # should save it
```

Comment: can you just print `o.points` manually to see what does it contain?

Comment: o.points works inside a different view. I am not sure if b.score works.  If I wanted to test it and print it, how do I print it? I can't get it to work with the django template system.

Comment: can you print it in the python console, by just a simple `print o.points` and it will be printed in the console

Comment: o.points in the console gives me the value 10, which matches what we have in our admin.

Comment: is this `o.points` an Integer? Can you test it by printing `print type(o.points)`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to specify which Score instance you are trying to query.

Assuming you had created one before, and it has primary key 1, you can access it using:

```
b = Score.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Alternatively, if it's the first time, you could run:

```
b, created = Score.objects.get_or_create(pk=1)
```

`created` will be true if you just created it